# Java regular expression OR operator

Tags: java, regex

This may be a dumb question, but I couldn't find it anywhere:

How can I use the java OR regular expression operator (|) without parentheses?

e.g:
    Tel|Phone|Fax

Comment: Looks ok, what problem are you having?

Comment: yeah, should work.  cletus, danben, and myself agree.  also, @danben - my name is Dan Beam, lol, so close!

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can just use the pipe on its own:

```
"string1|string2"
```

for example:

```
String s = "string1, string2, string3";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("string1|string2", "blah"));
```

Output:

```
blah, blah, string3
```

The main reason to use parentheses is to limit the scope of the alternatives:

```
String s = "string1, string2, string3";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("string(1|2)", "blah"));
```

has the same output. but if you just do this:

```
String s = "string1, string2, string3";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("string1|2", "blah"));
```

you get:

```
blah, stringblah, string3
```

because you've said "string1" or "2".

If you don't want to capture that part of the expression use `?:`:

```
String s = "string1, string2, string3";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("string(?:1|2)", "blah"));
```

Comment: What if i need to delimit these strings from other pieces of the regex that are also strings? e.g. eee(ff|gg)eee  Do I have to use parentheses?

Comment: Ah nevermind.  Your update fixes it.  The last example is what I was looking for.  Thanks!