# How can I provide an OR operator in regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match my string to one sequence or another, and it has to match at least one of them.

For `and` I learned it can be done with:

```
(?=one)(?=other)
```

Is there something like this for OR?

I am using Java, Matcher and Pattern classes.

Comment: check out this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031805/java-regular-expression-or-operator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking about regexes, you definitely should begin your journey into Regex wonderland here: [Regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

What you *currently* need is the `|` (pipe character)

To match the strings `one` OR `other`, use:

```
(one|other)
```

or if you don't want to store the matches, just simply

```
one|other
```

To be **Java** specific, [this article is very good at explaining the subject](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

You will have to use your patterns this way:

```
//Pattern and Matcher
Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(myPatternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myStringToMatch);
boolean isNextMatch = matcher.find(); //find next match, it exists, 
if(isNextMatch) {
    String matchedString = myStrin.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end());
}
```

Please note, there are much more possibilities regarding [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) then what I displayed here...

```
//String functions
boolean didItMatch = myString.matches(myPatternString); //same as Pattern.matches();
String allReplacedString = myString.replaceAll(myPatternString, replacement)
String firstReplacedString = myString.replaceFirst(myPatternString, replacement)
String[] splitParts = myString.split(myPatternString, howManyPartsAtMost);
```

Also, I'd highly recommend using online regex checkers such as [Regexplanet (Java)](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) or [regex101](https://regex101.com/), they make your life a lot easier!

Comment: Neither of your links link to Java-specific info. In particular refiddle doesn't provide Java info at all

Answer (score 4):

The "or" operator is spelled `|`, for example `one|other`.

All the operators are listed in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can separate with a pipe thus:

```
Pattern.compile("regexp1|regexp2");
```

See [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/capturing_groups_alternatives.shtml) for a couple of simple examples.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `|` character for **OR**

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("exp1|exp2");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher("Input_data");
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers are already given, use the pipe '|' operator. In addition to that, it might be useful to test your regexp in a regexp tester without having to run your application, for example:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html