# How to set multiple matches in a custom VS Code tmLanguage file?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm making my own language for a project (it's a simple one, but it'll be extremely helpful), and trying to add support to it on VS Code.

Since there are quite a few types that are meant to be of the same classification, I figured it'd be nice to do something like:

```
"match":"str col num etc"
```

But that doesn't work. Is there a way to avoid creating a match for every type?

Also, this kinda should be on another topic but is there any documentation or something explaining how to properly use tmLanguage or how to create syntax for languages on VS Code? I haven't found anything really. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really tmLanguage specific, what you're essentially asking is how to do that with a regex (since that's what tmLanguage uses). So https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602954/how-can-i-provide-an-or-operator-in-regular-expressions or similar should help.

Comment: Hey @Gama11 ! Sorry for not replying earlier. Indeed, what I was looking for is exactly that. Thanks!