# How to split a string by comma followed by a colon in java?

Tags: java, split

I'm a java newbie and I'm curious to know how to split a string that starts with a comma and gets followed by a colon towards the end.
 An example of such string would be?

```
-10,3,15,4:38
5,15,8,2:8
```

Could it be like this?

```
sections = line.split(",");
tokens = sections[3].split(":");
```

or is it even possible to split line which the file is read into twice?

```
tokens = line.split(",");
tokens = line.split(":");
```

I also tried this but it gave me an ArrayOutOfBound error

```
tokens = line.split("[,:]");
```

Any contribution would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into java built in class stringTokenizer

Comment: ok I will, thanks @JackWilliams

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a regular expression in the split section such as

```
line.split(",|;");
```

Haven't tested it but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Here is something that can help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031805/java-regular-expression-or-operator

Comment: Thanks for contributing. I do get it and I'll try it too :)

Comment: awesome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way, if you want it for a general case, the method basically takes in the string array, splits each string at each index in the array and adds them to an ArrayList. You can try it, it works.

```
public static void splitStrings(String[] str){

            String[] temp1 =null;//initialize temp array

            List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){

                temp1=str[i].split(",|:");

                 for (String item : temp1) {
                     itemList.add(item);
                  }
                 //Only print the final result of collection once iteration has ended
                 if(i==str.length-1){

                     System.out.println(itemList);
                 }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I totally understand your question correctly. But if you first want to split by `,` and then by `:`, you can call `split()` function twice

```
String[] str = {"-10,3,15,4:38", "5,15,8,2:8"};
    
for (String s: str) {
    String[] temp = s.split(",")[3].split(":");
    System.out.println(temp[0] + " " + temp[1]);
}
```

Output:

> 4 38
>
> 2 8