# One expression to ignore special symbols, numbers, and spacing? Java

Tags: java, replaceall

What I have so far is:

```
userSent = userSent.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); //replaces all spaces with no spacing
userSent = userSent.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""); //remove all special characters
userSent = userSent.replaceAll("[0-9]", ""); //remove all numbers from string
```

I would like to simplify this to one expression if possible using Java, thanks a bunch.

Comment: You can use the `|` in regular expressions for or, although leaving it like this is probably a good idea for readability sake.

Comment: If you want to replace anything that's not a letter, why not just replace all `[^a-zA-Z]`. Then you don't need the additional statements for removing digits and spaces. You can further simplify that my making it a case-insensitive regex, though it's fairly terse either way.

Comment: this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031805/java-regular-expression-or-operator) may help you about how use  or in regex

Answer (score 1):

Those three replaces are equivalent to this:

```
userSent = userSent.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

<sup>(The set of characters that are "not a letter" includes numbers and spaces.)</sup>

However, I suspect that this is not what you actually want because it removes every character that is not in the Latin alphabet and mashes them all into a single "word".  Is that really what you want?  (To my mind, it doesn't match the problem description in your Question's title.)

My advice would be to make sure that the 3 replaces do what you actually want (in other words ... **test them in combination**) before you try to combine them into a single regex.

Comment: Thanks, this works for what i need it for =) I will try to work on more accurate titles

Comment: OK ... if you say this is really what you need ... we have to take you at your word.